# Do I need to validate entities if I have already validated the DTO?

Tags: java, validation, spring-mvc, jpa, bean-validation

I had a little misunderstanding. Let's say I have such an entity:

```
@Entity
public class Item {
    private String description;
}
```

As well as DTO to this entity:

```
public class ItemDto {
    private String description;
}
```

As you already understand, all controllers work only with the DTO, that is, I get the DTO from the client part, and then convert it into an entity, and so on.So, I decided to validate the DTO:

```
 public class ItemDto {
      @Max(value = 100, message = "Description must not exceed 100 characters")
      private String description;
 }
```

Validation works well, but I have a question: do I need to validate entities as well? I always thought that annotations for validation in entity are useless because you still create the necessary tables yourself and set the necessary restrictions. But then the question arises, should entities correspond to the table in the database at all? That is, for example, if I have a `NOT NULL` constraint in the table for a field, should I also put the `@NotNull` annotation over this field in the entity? The DTO is also not clear. I'm validating the DTO, but this probably doesn't guarantee complete data protection.in other words, in theory, some programmer might decide to do something directly with the entity, but it isn't validated. All this will lead to an error. Or there may be a situation where restrictions are set in the table in the database, but there are no restrictions in the entity.in other words, you can assign any value to the entity, but an error occurs when adding it to the database. Help me deal with the situation. I'm sorry if I didn't explain it very well.

Comment: This is a very good question. I am dealing with the same situation right now. I have all validation in the DTOs and none in the Entities. This avoids having to duplicate validations but there is still a risk, like you mentioned, that a developer can directly create and entity in an invalid state. Code reviews, for now, help with this. I am interested in hearing about how other people approach this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You said

> Should entities correspond to the table in the database at all? That
>   is, for example, if I have a `NOT NULL` constraint in the table for a
>   field, should I also put the `@NotNull` annotation over this field in
>   the entity?

[Bean Validation](https://beanvalidation.org/)'s purpose is to be used for validating beans. So, for cases where you are not validating the entity, there is clearly no point of placing an unused annotation.

You said

> I'm validating the DTO, but this probably doesn't guarantee complete.
>   data protection

[`JPA`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/persistence/package-summary.html) annotations serve this purpose. For example, in the `NOT NULL` scenario you mentioned, you can use [`@Column`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/index.html?javax/persistence/Column.html) as:

```java
@Column(nullable = false)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [SmartConstraints](https://github.com/jruillier/smartconstraints) (I'm the author) to validate both Entity and DTO.

After annotating your entity (e.g with `@NotNull` on `description` property, which is usefull for JPA), you could use `@ValidDescription` in you DTO on `description` property.

Using SmartConstraints, you avoid risks of constraints de-synchronisations between your Entity and your DTO.

Sometimes, on multiple operations, you'll have to use multiple DTOs to carry data intended to update your entity. You could reuse `@ValidXXX`, for the appropriate fields.

Comment: Very interesting concept for clean architecture. When do u plan for a first "release" ?

Comment: Hi @Tristan, thanks for you interest :-) You can use SmartConstraints with those maven coordinates :
`eu.aronnax.smartconstraints:smartconstraints-annotation:0.4.0` (as a provided dependency) and `eu.aronnax.smartconstraints:smartconstraints-annotationprocessor:0.4.0` (as an annotation processor)
Let me know if you need any assistance.

Comment: Oh ok, maybe I misread " Stay tuned for incoming release", I thought u were planning for a 1.0.0 and this was considered as "beta" or "alpha" (source : https://github.com/jruillier/smartconstraints).

Comment: You're right, I'll try to clarify that README on GitHub, and add a roadmap for incoming changes.

Comment: @jruillier Not a bad idea, but I would have gone a bit further. I'd image an annotation on the DTO that links to the entity, and a library would copy all validation annotations from the entity to the DTO based on matching field names.